# Compute the sum of the power series in a closed form.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left (\left ( \frac{n+1}{n+3}  \right ) ^n  \right )^n x^{2n} $

Please help me to write the sum of the series function in a closed form.

**Please note that my book asks to compute the value of f(5)(0), this means the value of the fifth derivative of the sum function f(x), in x=0.**

Comment: Why do you believe there is a closed form?  Wait, maybe I said that too passively—I bet you a thousand dollars that there is no closed form.

Comment: My book asks to compute f(5)(0), the value of the fifth derivative of f(x) in the point x=0.

Comment: $IV = 4$, not $5$.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, corrected! :-)

Comment: Your function is an even function in $x$ and you asks for a derivative of odd order at $0$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given an absolutely convergent (in a neighborhood of $0$) power series $f(x)=a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots$, then we have $f^{(5)} (0) = 5! \cdot a_5$ by term-wise differentiation.  In this particular case, we can get the answer without even putting pen on paper...